# Django: get count of ForeignKey item in template?

Tags: django

Straightforward question - apologies if it is a duplicate, but I can't find the answer if so.

I have a User model and a Submission model, like this:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey('User')
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250 )
```

How can I show the number of Submissions made by each user in the **template**? I've tried `{{ user.submission.count }}`, like this:

```
for user in users:
    {{ user.name }} ({{ user.submission.count }} submissions)
```

but no luck...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
{{user.submission_set.all|length}}
```

Comment: Yeah, you can even do {{ user.submission_set.count }}. Be sure to read up on django relations. They are so important to understanding models well.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Comment: Thanks - I've read up but I have another quick question. If the Submission class has a boolean field called 'problem_submission', is there a way to get the count of all the related submissions where the 'problem_submission' field isn't set to True?

Comment: Something like that would probably be best with a custom template tag (which are really easy to write)

Comment: can i do ```{{ user.submission_set.all|length -1 }}``` in it

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the "set". It should be `{{ user.submission_set.count }}`. You can always change the related name, but the default is `<fk class name>_set`.  For more see the [relations documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/models/#relationships).