# Changes on model instance not shown in Tempalate

Tags: django

I'm new to django and I'm trying to create a like buttton. When I click on the button I can see that the Like model gets updated with user and the post that the user liked. Then I also see that the total likes in the Post model gets incremented by 1. But the template it self still shows 0 likes.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    categorys = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=post_image_file_path)
```

'''

```
class Like(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

'''

```
 path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
 path('like/', views.like, name='like'),
```

'''

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    all_posts = services.get_all_posts()
    all_categorys = services.get_all_categorys()
    all_tags = services.get_all_tags()
    context = {'all_posts': all_posts, 'all_categorys': all_categorys,
               'all_tags': all_tags}

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def like(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        model = get_user_model()
        postid = request.GET.get('postid')
        user = model.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        post = Post.objects.get(id=postid)

        if Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).exists():
           Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).delete()
           update_likes = Post.objects.get(id=post.id)
           update_likes.likes -= 1  # change field
           update_likes.save()  # this will update only
        else:
           like = Like.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
           update_likes = Post.objects.get(id=post.id)
           update_likes.likes += 1  # change field
           update_likes.save()  # this will update only
    return redirect('blog:home')
```

'''

```
   {% for post in all_posts %}

       html...


      <form action="{% url 'blog:like'%}" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="{{ post.id }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Like</button>
      </form>

      <p>total = {{ post.likes }}</p>

   {% endfor %}
```

'''

I'm sure this is not the best way to do this but I like to understand why the template isn't updated with the new value after redirecting to home view.

Comment: If you try to refresh everything works fine ?

Comment: Just an advice, instead of having a `likes` field on the post model, you can just get the count of all `like` objects related to the post. That way you don't have to worry about incrementing/decrementing the `likes` field all the time. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617889/django-get-count-of-foreignkey-item-in-template

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use ajax for the automate template update, otherwise you'll have to refresh each time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkPRtQf6oQ8)

[Also add the never_cache decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers)

In your view at views.py file

```py
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def yourView(...):
    ....
```

or if you have a class based view

```py
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

class YourView(View):
    @never_cache
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank, I understand but as of now even if I refresh nothing happens to the template all tough the models are updated correctly. Unless I restart the server then the template gets updated.

Comment: Check my updated answer, probably what you need is @never_cache decorator